# .width() giving error $(...)[0].width is not a function?

Tags: jquery

I have a table, and I'm trying to find the width of each td in the table. I've tried all kinds of variations of: `$("td")[0].width()`, but none of them work, getting an error of: `"Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].width is not a function"` everytime.

I'm importing jQuery first, before my other JS files, (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js), and I'm using .width() not .width.

Any ideas?

Comment: `[0]` gets the DOM element - and DOM elements don't have a `.width()` method. If you want the first elem, use `.first()` - `$("td").first().width()`

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("td")[0]` is a DOM element not a jquery object. Simply wrap it as jquery `$($("td")[0]).width()`

You need to get width of each `td` so you could use something like

```
$.each('td', function() {
    var currentTDWidth = $(this).width(); // more code here
});
```

Comment: Why have you added `#` against td?

Comment: my bad. I wrote in a hurry and didn't look. Edited

Comment: Other answers were helpful too, this one worked. Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 2):

Use eq(0) instead of [0] to preserve the jQuery object that has the width() function.

Answer (score 2):

while you said  *I'm trying to find the width of each td in the table* so you need to loop through tds by using `.each()` ..

```
$('td').each(function(){
   alert($(this).width());
});
```

and to select specific td there are more ways

by using `:eq()` selector

```
$('td:eq(0)');   // index start from 0
```

or `.eq()` in jquery

```
$('td').eq(0)        // index start from 0
```

or `:nth-child()` selector

```
$('td:nth-child(1)');    // index start from 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td")[0]
```

Is a DOM Level element and not a jQuery Object. and `.width()` is a jQuery method, so you literally can't use it on that. *Do either of the following:*

```
$("td").eq(0).width(); // On a jQuery object
$("td")[0].offsetWidth; // On a DOM Level Element.
```

**To fetch the width of all the elements use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**

```
$('td').each(function(){
   alert($(this).width());
});
```